# CSS Border of specific length in nested elements

Tags: html, css

I have nested nested div-elements like this

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="sub1">
        <div class="sub2">
            Hello Worlds!!
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With styles as

```
.main {
    width:200px;
    border-bottom : solid 1px #0000FF;
 }

.sub1 {
    width:300px;
    border-bottom : solid 3px #00FF00;
}

.sub2 {
    border-bottom : solid 3px #FF0000;
}
```

Is there any way to set border length of class "sub2" to 200px ie. same of main class?
Here is the [example: http://jsfiddle.net/1Lygjmvj/](http://jsfiddle.net/1Lygjmvj)

Comment: do you mean main to be 200px, then sub1 to be 300px and then sub2 to be 200px again? like this? http://jsfiddle.net/1Lygjmvj/2/

Comment: @ochi that's how I exactly want, but do not want to set width: 200px; to sub2 in css because size of main may change after loading.

Comment: and does sub2 have to be nested inside sub1? if it is independent of sub1, you can set the width of sub2 to be 100% (same as its parent, i.e. main)

Comment: Yes sub2 has to be nested in sub1. May be I should use jQuery to get the width of main at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is to set *.sub2* width to *200px*. You know width of your *.main* element so it's not required to do this other way.

Your styles should just look like this:

```
.main {
    width:200px;
    border-bottom : solid 1px #0000FF;
 }

.sub1 {
    width:300px;
    border-bottom : solid 3px #00FF00;
}

.sub2 {
    border-bottom : solid 3px #FF0000;
}
```

But if you really, really need to do this depending on *.main* width, because your top parent div don't have fixed width you have to do this in Javascript.
You can for example use this code if you're using JQuery:

```
$(function () {
    var list = $(".sub2");
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        $(list[i]).width( $(list[i]).parent().parent().width() );
    }
});
```

This code will set width of all elements that contains class *.sub2* to parent of it's parent width when page will load.

Comment: thanks @Skorek what I did is like this: http://jsfiddle.net/1Lygjmvj/7/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#main {
   max-width:200px !important;
   border-bottom : solid 1px #0000FF;
}

#sub1 {
    width:300px;
    border-bottom : solid 3px #00FF00;
}
#sub2 {
    width:200px;
    border-bottom : solid 3px #FF0000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add an empty element after `sub2`, and move `sub1`'s styles to it:

```css
#main {
  width:200px;
  border-bottom : solid 15px blue;
}

#sub2 {
  border-bottom : solid 13px red;
}

#sub3 {
  width:300px;
  border-bottom : solid 10px green;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="sub1">
    <div id="sub2">
      Hello Worlds!!
    </div>
    <div id="sub3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```